# Weird output printed to the error screen (System.err)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running three threads in my main program for testing purposes. Everything works fine and it does what it is supposed to do.

However, I noticed that on the console I get the following output (in color red):

```
[Stage 242:=====================================================> (36 + 1) / 37]

[Stage 246:==============================================>        (31 + 1) / 37]

[Stage 249:====================================================>  (36 + 1) / 38]

[Stage 260:=================================================>     (35 + 1) / 39]

[Stage 263:==================================================>    (37 + 1) / 40]

[Stage 267:==================================================>    (37 + 1) / 40]

[Stage 270:=====================================================> (40 + 1) / 41]

[Stage 274:==================================================>    (38 + 1) / 41]

[Stage 277:================================================>      (37 + 1) / 42]

[Stage 281:============================================>          (34 + 1) / 42]

[Stage 288:=================================================>     (39 + 1) / 43]

[Stage 291:===========================================>           (35 + 1) / 44]

[Stage 295:================================================>      (39 + 1) / 44]

[Stage 298:==========================================>            (35 + 1) / 45]
```

And the program keeps printing these continues lines on and on as my main program keeps running. Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of this and if it affects my program at all?

EDIT: Here is my code so far. One thread generates a file every second, the other thread has a function that reads that file and then deletes it, and the last thread continuously asks the user for input and based on that input it effects a function:

```
    static PredictiveModelDemo pmDemo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pmDemo = new PredictiveModelDemo();
        new Thread(new generateFiles()).start();
        new Thread(new feedModel()).start();
        new Thread(new makePrediction()).start();
    }

    static class generateFiles implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ZK0GJXO\\Documents\\NoOfTrades.txt");
            int i = 1;
            while(true){
                try {
                    if(!file.exists()){
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\ZK0GJXO\\Documents\\NoOfTrades.txt");
                        writer.print(i * 15);
                        writer.close();
                        i++;
                    }
                    else{
                        i++;
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class feedModel implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pmDemo.feedModel();
        }
    }
    static class makePrediction implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Enter P to make a prediction: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String response = in.next();
            while(true){
                if(response.toUpperCase().equals("P")){
                    pmDemo.makePrediction();
                    response = "";
                    System.out.println("Enter P to make a prediction: ");
                    response = in.next();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have a console log writing out every 3 lines? that's what it looks like.. it doesn't affect your program if so

Comment: It's doing that because of what you wrote on that line. No, not that line, the line before. (It's very hard to say why code is doing something if you don't show the code...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red output is the stderr output. It is likely the logging output of one of the libraries that you're using, wherever `PredictiveModelDemo` is coming from.

Are you using any logging libraries, like JUL or log4j? If you are, and if the libraries are using java's logging framework correctly, you can filter out log lines you're not interested in.

It's also possible that a library is directly calling `System.err.println`, although this is *strongly* discouraged. If so, there's not much that you can do about it.

Either way, it shouldn't impact your program.

Comment: I'm using Apache Spark 2.1 and this library does use log4j. I know my program won't be affected at all, but seeing this messages is annoying and makes my testing difficult to understand. Anyway of how can I get rid with them? I have used this library before and I've never had this output printed to the console before. It all started when I started using multiple threads.

Comment: So I got rid of them by using this: `System.err.close();`